# ODF Toolkit-Casting Problem

Tags: java, odf, odftoolkit

I am developing a webservice to create an odt document with odf toolkit. I did use below code to create a new document but i am getting an casting error. What o you think about it? How can i create formatted(colored etc) text? Thanks

My Code Just

```
    try
{
    TextDocument outputOdt=TextDocument.newTextDocument();
    outputOdt.save("C:\\Users\\TheIntersect\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\webWord\\web\\Documents\\docx\\quick.odt");
    return "Succesfull";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

Error

org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfAlienElement cannot be cast to org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.meta.MetaInitialCreatorElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. It is interesting but it is not working with Win7 and jdk6. It works with JDK7 and Win7. It also works jdk6 with WinXp.